# How does one factorise this algebraic expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you factorise this algebraic expression:

$$126x^3-3x^2+3x-1$$

Comment: $(21x^2+3x+1)(6x-1)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
126x^3-3x^2+3x-1&=125x^3+x^3-3x^2+3x-1\\
&=(5x)^3+(x-1)^3\\
&=(5x+x-1)[(5x)^2-(5x)(x-1)+(x-1)^2]\\
&=(6x-1)(21x^2+3x+1)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Using the rational root theorem, we get $x=\frac{1}{6}$. Therefore, we know $6x-1$ is a factor. Dividing, we get $21x^2+3x+1$. This cannot be simplified any further, leaving you with: $$126x^3-3x^2+3x-1=(6x-1)(21x^2+3x+1)$$